# Javalite - skip running migrations

Tags: javalite

When I run `mvn clean install`, `db-migrator-maven-plugin` tries to run migrations and fails as there is no one for the moment:

```
[INFO] Trying migrations at: /Users/XXXX/projects/decXXXX/src/migrations 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.643 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-11-07T17:19:24+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/309M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.javalite:db-migrator-maven-plugin:1.4.13:migrate (dev_migrations) on project decastore: Execution dev_migrations of goal org.javalite:db-migrator-maven-plugin:1.4.13:migrate failed: No migrations are found at: /Users/XXXX/projects/XXXXX/src/migrations -> [Help 1]
```

I took a look in its docs and found nothing. Any tips on how to achieve that ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you have no migrations, you do not need a migrator. REmove the migrator configuration to overcome the error message and failed build.

Comment: Thank you, Igor for the response. Sure, I'll need to use migrations in the near future. I just believed that I could it get working (run `mvn clean install` for example) in the very beginning of a project setup phase, when there are no migrations yet.

Comment: once you have migrations, the migrator will work as expected